# Laravel Modeling System

Tags: laravel, validation, model

I have been using Laravel for a couple weeks now and I love the framework. However, with models is there any actual robust system? Creating models, like the user model, just seems to be string arrays of what you do and do not want modified in queries. The place I see validation of the models is in the controller (through $this->validate()) and/or migrations creating the tables.

I just wanted to know if there is a certain place I am missing or not implementing. My brain is referencing something like ASP.NET's decorators that add validation to data models. Thank you!

Comment: You can validate your model in beforeSave hook. However, decorators and annotations are not supported in php natively, but Doctrine ORM framework, which inspired by java Hibernate ORM (java has annotations). Doctrine implemented these annotations in phpdoc blocks.

Comment: And yes, that's pretty weird that laravel validates not models but request data or arrays, but this is what I miss in Symfony)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I just figured I would ask to ensure I was not leaving out a tool that would be very powerful. Appreciate it!